# Identify a truth-teller among a group of truth-tellers and (honest) liars.

Tags: combinatorics, logic, puzzle, combinatorial-game-theory, extremal-combinatorics

This question is inspired by this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332801/a-knight-and-knave-problem).  In that thread, a liar may both tells lies and truths.  However, in my version, ***liars always lie***.

> **Main Question.**  A group of people consists of $m$ truth-tellers (who always are truthful) and $n$ liars (who always lie) where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers.  In the group, everybody knows whether another from the group is a truth-teller or a liar.  You do not have this information whatsoever, and cannot discern the distinction between a truth-teller and a liar, but you know the values of $m$ and $n$.
>
> The aim is to identify a truth-teller within the group.  You can only ask a person $A$ about another person $B$ whether $B$ is a liar.  If $N(m,n)$ is the smallest possible number of questions you need to guarantee that the job can be accomplished, then determine the value of $N(m,n)$ for each pair $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\times\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.

**Known Results:**

- If $m=n$, then $N(m,n)$ does not exist.
- If $m\neq n$, then *[Mike Earnest](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/177399/mike-earnest)* showed that $$N(m,n)\leq \max\big\{n,2\,\min\{m,n\}\big\}\,.$$
- If $m<n$, then *[Todor Markov](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/615317/todor-markov)*  gave an improvement: $$N(m,n)\leq \max\big\{n-1,2\,\min\{m,n\}\big\}\,.$$
- If $m>n$, then the user *[fedja](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12992/fedja)* found that $$N(m,n)\leq 2n-1\,.$$
- For all $m>1$, $N(m,1)=1$.
- I know that $N(2,3)=3$, $N(2,4)=4$, and $N(2,m)=m-1$ for $m\geq 5$.
- The user *fedja* and I discovered that $N(3,2)=2$ and $N(m,2)=3$ for all $m\geq 4$.
- The user *fedja* found that $N(m,3)=4$ for all sufficiently large $m$, and $N(m,4)=7$ for all sufficiently large $m$.

---

However, if you want to solve the following generalized version of the question in the linked [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332801/a-knight-and-knave-problem) here, then you are very welcome.  In other words, I would also love to see the answer to this auxiliary question.  (It is also good if you put your answer to the question below in the [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332801/a-knight-and-knave-problem) above.)

> **Auxiliary Question.**  A group of people consists of $m$ truth-tellers (who always are truthful) and $n$ drunkards (who may tell both truths or lies) where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers.  In the group, everybody knows whether another from the group is a truth-teller or a drunkard.  You do not have this information whatsoever, and cannot discern the distinction between a truth-teller and a drunkard, but you know the values of $m$ and $n$.
>
> The aim is to identify a truth-teller within the group.  You can only ask a person $A$ about another person $B$ whether $B$ is a drunkard.  If $M(m,n)$ is the smallest possible number of questions you need to guarantee that the job can be accomplished, then determine the value of $M(m,n)$ for each pair $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\times\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.

Comment: Your title reminds me of the film An Honest Liar, a biography of the illusionist (magician) and debunker James Randi.

Comment: Can you describe how to solve $N(1,100)$ in $2\cdot\min(1,100)=2$ tests?

Comment: @MikeEarnest  I seem to have made an assumption that $m>n$ in my old (faulty) proof.  Therefore, I redacted my claim.

Comment: It is possible to succeed in $\max(n,2\cdot\min(m,n))$ queries by modifying your original strategy. One by one, query $X$ about other people. If $X$ says everyone is truthful, you are done after $n$ tests (because these $n+1$ people cannot all be liars, so they are all truthful). Otherwise, if $X$ says at least one person is a liar, then your argument shows you are done after $2\cdot\min(m,n)$ tests.

Comment: We can do improve @MikeEarnest's value slightly for the case $m<n$ (in the other case fedja's is already better). If $m<n$, the moment X has named $n-1$ as truthful, we know X and they are all the liars, and anyone else is truthful. So we have, if $m<n, N(m,n) = \max(n-1, 2m)$

Comment: I saw you updated the post, however if $m>n$ I don't thin you have the -1. Only when $m<n$.

Comment: @TodorMarkov Oh, right!  Thanks!

Comment: If $2^{k-1}\le n < 2^k$, then $N(m,n) \le 2n-B(n)$ for $m\ge 2^k$ (this was already known) and $N(m,n) \le 2n-B(n)-1$ for $n<m<2^k$. It seems to me that equality holds in both cases, but I have no proof.

Comment: If one could prove that $N(m+2^{k-1},n+2^{k-1})\ge N(m,n)+2^k-1$ for $m>n$ and $k>0$, then one should be able to prove the equalities. But I don't even know how to prove $N(m+1,n+1)\ge N(m,n)+1$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $B(k)$ denote the number of ones that $k$ has when written in binary.

> If $m>n$, then $N(m,n)\le 2n+1-B(2n+1)$.

This corresponds with the bounds $N(m,3)\le 4$ and $N(m,4)\le 7$ mentioned in the post.

*Proof:* Take any $2n+1$ people and ignore the rest. The majority of those people are truth tellers, and we need to find a truth teller, where the only allowed operation is to select two people and learn whether or not they are the same identity. This is exactly the situation discussed in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01275672), which provides an algorithm to succeed in the claimed number of tests.

At any point in the algorithm, the people will be divided into groups, such that people in a group are known to have the same identity as each other. Initially, everyone is in their own group. Repeatedly, find two groups of equal size, and compare a representative from each. If they are equal, then merge the groups. If not, then throw both groups in the "trash." Throwing away these two groups leaves a majority of truth-tellers among the non-trash groups.

The algorithm terminates when all the non-trash groups have different sizes. These groups are all sizes which are powers of two, so the largest group must be larger than the sum of the others, implying it must be made of truth tellers. In the worst case, no groups were thrown away, so these sizes correspond to the binary representation of $2n+1$. It takes $2^k-1$ operations to form a group of size $2^k$; adding these up, you get $2n+1-B(2n+1)$.

Comment: Yeah, this upper bound works even in the setting when liars can say anything they want (though I prefer to write it as $2n-B(n)$ and derive it from the recursion $f(n)\le n+f([n/2])$). That is the easy part. The hard part is the estimate from below. The best one I currently know is $2n-O(\sqrt n)$. Can you do any better for large $n$?

Comment: @fedja I think I can prove the matching lower bound when $m\ge 2n+1$ by adapting the proof in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002001909390135V) (you need access from an institution to read). That is, $N(m,n)=2n-B(n)$ when $m\ge 2n+1$.  But I do not have the energy to reword that two-page proof.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look it up when I am at work tomorrow.

Comment: I looked at it. Very cute paper but I still do not see how to modify it for our setting. We have a completely different decision tree now both in terms of the number of admissible colorings and in terms of leaves (I mean the information that we have exactly $n$ liars is not the same as the information that the truth-tellers are the majority). So if you could just clearly indicate what is the subset of admissible coloring schemes you want to look at and what is the new claim about the leaves in the decision tree, it would be very helpful.

Comment: @fedja Let $S$ be a subset of $2n+1$ people. We will only pay attention to information about the subset of truth-tellers in $S$. Initially, there are $2^{2n}$ possibilities for the set of truth-tellers in $S$. Letting $x\in S$, there are $2^{2n-1}+\frac12\binom{2n}n$ possibilities where $x$ is a truth teller. As you make comparisons, the number of possibilities is always a power of two, and the same goes for possibilities where $x$ is a truth-teller. Etc, etc

Comment: "As you make comparisons, the number of possibilities is always a power of two." Nope. The questioner may start with getting some information about people outside your set of $2n+1$. Say, he figures out that there are 5  opposite type pairs there. That restricts your available colorings of 2n+1 selected people by the condition that one of the types should be of size n-5 or less, completely screwing the "power of 2 property". Am I missing something?

Comment: @fedja You are right. That could be fixed by assuming $m\ge 6n+1$, say. After $2n$ tests, you will have seen at most $4n$ of the people, so at least $2n+1$ can be used make arbitrary subsets of truth-tellers for $S$.

Comment: Again I'm missing something. First of all, you were going to *fix* $2n+1$ people to define the configuration space and that should be done *independently* of the questioner moves. Also, once the questioner figures out something about other people, *arbitrary* subsets are no longer possible even within $2n+1$ he has never asked about.